# How to rotate or flip a component in dymola 2020X

Tags: modelica, dymola

There is no `rotate` or `flip` option in dymola 2020x, is there a shortkey for these operation or I should do this anywhere else?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the Dymola shortcut keys when one or more components are selected:

- `CTRL + R`: rotate counterclockwise
- `CRTL + SHIFT + R`: rotate clockwise
- `V`: vertical flip
- `H`: horizontal flip

Best regards
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Does an overview of all keyboard shortcuts in Dymola exist somewhere? Maybe even on a single page, in printable layout as a cheat sheet?

Comment: @matth: Yes, in the first Dymola User Manual, Section 2.8 (for 2018 at least).

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the keyboard shortcuts recommended by Rene Just Nielsen, Dymola 2020x of course still allows to rotate and flip components using the GUI. The commands are accessible via the "Arrange" button, which is only clickable when you select a component first.

[image: Dymola 2020x screenshot with Arrange menu]